# Internal transform error in cloudformation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam-cli

I get an "Internal transform" error when deploying this template. I use a Mapping to transform dev and prod settings. This works for single values but cloudformation is choking on trying to transform the Events config. This passes `aws cloudformation validate-template` whats wrong with my config?:

I use a Mapping to transform dev and prod settings. This works for single values but SAM is choking on trying to transform the Events config, whats wrong with my config?:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'

Parameters:
  env:
    Description: Config map for transforming template with dev or prod values
    Type: String
    Default: dev

# Template uses !FindInMap along with env parameter to reference dev or prod values defined here
Mappings:
  ConfigMap:
    dev:
      awsAccount: 'dev'
      configFile: 'dev_config.yaml'
      cloudwatchEvents: !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
    prod:
      awsAccount: 'prod'
      configFile: 'prod_config.yaml'
      cloudwatchEvents:
        Schedule1:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Schedule: rate(3 minutes)

Resources:
  myfunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ../build
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 30
      Events:
        !FindInMap
            - ConfigMap
            - !Ref env
            - cloudwatchEvents

      Environment:
        Variables:
          config_file: !FindInMap
            - ConfigMap
            - !Ref env
            - configFile

      Tags:
        account: !FindInMap
          - ConfigMap
          - !Ref env
          - awsAccount
        blah: derp
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo after !FindInMap, you are missing a colon after that. It should be !FindInMap:

Comment: no that syntax is correct. this template works if you removed the cloudwatchEvents mappings and Events config node